# USART3_IRQHandler() is continuously called with LL_USART_IsActiveFlag_TXE set

Tags: serial-port, stm32, interrupt, irq, stm32h743

I'm to developing my own serial code (rather than using CubeMX's HAL) to interface an existing protocol codebase which needs low-level serial features.

`USART3_IRQHandler()` is being called repeatedly (and hence `serial::serial_irq_handler()` too.

```
/**
  * @brief This function handles USART3 global interrupt.
  */
void USART3_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART3_IRQn 0 */
  serial_irq_handler(&usart3);
  /* USER CODE END USART3_IRQn 0 */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART3_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART3_IRQn 1 */
}
```

serial.c:

```
/**
 * @brief Should be called only by UART/USARTx_IRQHandler()
 */
void serial_irq_handler(struct serial *serial)
{
    // "while" is used in case we decide to turn on the limited FIFOs (USARTs only).
    while (LL_USART_IsActiveFlag_RXNE(serial->usart)) {
        uint8_t b = LL_USART_ReceiveData8(serial->usart);
        circbuf_push(&serial->rxcircbuf, b);
    }

    if (LL_USART_IsActiveFlag_TXE(serial->usart)) {
        LL_USART_ClearFlag_TC(serial->usart);
        serial->txbusy = 0;
    }
}
```

(`serial->usart == USART3` in the code above.)

I think that the problem is that I am clearing the wrong flag (TC instead of TXE).

Is this the cause of the issue?

I cannot clear TXE, as `LL_USART_ClearFlag_TXE()` does not exist.

If I comment out `LL_USART_EnableIT_TXE(serial->usart);` in the intialisation code, the issue goes away (but I then cannot then see if the serial port is free to write to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong logic.

TXE interrupt should be enbled **only** if you have some data to send.

When you finish feeding the data register - you disable it.

It is logical that there is no TXE clear flag. **EMPTY** flag can be only cleared by making it *not empty*

> but I then cannot then see if the serial port is free to write to

You need to implement a buffer. And check if you have space in the buffer to place new data to send.

Comment: Thanks, I had misunderstood the flag.  When writing a byte, should it be `LL_USART_EnableIT_TXE()` followed by `LL_USART_TransmitData8()` or the other way around?

Comment: you still do not understand it.  Non of above.

Comment: Could you point me at a document?  The manual for the stm32h743 doesn't cover the usarts.

Comment: such a documents do not exist. When data arrives palce it into the buffer. Then enable TXE interrupt. in the interupt routine check if the  data is available in the bufefer if yes load it into the dasta register if not disable TXE interrupt.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've accepted it as I showed me that TXE flag should only be enabled when you send something.  I still don't get why I would need an additional buffer, and it's working fine without.  My question about the order of the calls remains, though its working fine as is.

Answer (score 0):

I had my logic wrong, as pointed out by P__J__.

The new code looks like this, and is working.

serial.c:

```
int serial_tx(struct serial *serial, uint8_t byte) {
    if (serial->txbusy) {
        serial->stats.txbusy++;
        return -1;
    }
    serial->txbusy = 1;
    LL_USART_TransmitData8(serial->usart, byte);
    LL_USART_EnableIT_TXE(serial->usart);
    serial->stats.txbytes++;
    return 0;
}

int serial_rx(struct serial *serial, uint8_t *out) {
    return circbuf_pop(&serial->rxcircbuf, out);
}

/*
 * @brief Should be called only by void UART/USARTx_IRQHandler()
 */
void serial_irq_handler(struct serial *serial)
{
    // while is used in case we decide to turn on the limited FIFOs (USARTs only).
    while (LL_USART_IsActiveFlag_RXNE(serial->usart)) {
        uint8_t b = LL_USART_ReceiveData8(serial->usart);
        circbuf_push(&serial->rxcircbuf, b);
    }

    if (LL_USART_IsActiveFlag_TXE(serial->usart)) {
        LL_USART_DisableIT_TXE(serial->usart);
        serial->txbusy = 0;
    }
}
```

I had to implement byte I/O, not buffered, as that what the higher (pre-existing) comms layers required.

-- Update --

Small variations on this code do not work.  I tried to involve the TXC flag, before being given a reference to the 3,000+ page manual for this chip.  Chapter 48 contains USART details.

https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00314099-stm32h742-stm32h743-753-and-stm32h750-value-line-advanced-arm-based-32-bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf